# Ionic Native Geocoder "Cannot find a location."

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, geocoder

I am using the Native Geocoder in my Ionic app. Documented here

> [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-geocoder/)
>
> [Github Repo](https://github.com/sebastianbaar/cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder)

This is the method in my provider -

```js
//This calls the Native geocoder and returns the geocoordinates. 
  getGeoCode(address: string): Promise<any> {
    console.log('The address key is - ' + address);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode(address)
        .then((nativegeocoordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult) => {
          console.log('The coordinates are - ' + JSON.stringify(nativegeocoordinates));
          let addressCoordinates: DeliveryAddressCoordinates = nativegeocoordinates;
          resolve(addressCoordinates);
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
          reject(error);
        });
    })
  }
```

The method accepts an address string as input. So I get the address from google places API, and pass the description here.

Now, for certain addresses, it just doesn't seem to find the coordinates, and returns a "Cannot find a location" message. For e.g. *"Bhadra Brookefields Apartment B Block, Kundanahalli Lake Road, Kundalahalli, Brookefield, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India"* is a valid address and returns the coordinates, while *"Times Square 42 Street Station, New York, NY, USA"* does not find a match and returns a message saying - "Cannot find a location".

For more information the "Cannot find a location" seems to be originating from the [cordova plugin code here on line #182.](https://github.com/sebastianbaar/cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder/blob/master/src/android/NativeGeocoder.java), where it is referencing the Android class.

Is this a known issue? Or is there something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one other person believes the plugin seems to be a bit of a hit/miss - a comment on this article below

[Ionic 2 – Geolocation and GeocodingIonic 2 – Geolocation and Geocoding](http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-geolocation-and-geocoding/)

The comment is from one Mr. Purple Edge, and I cannot link the comment itself because it is a disq, and not allowed by Stack.

So, I have resorted to what can be interpreted both as a solution or as a workaround. Instead of using the plugin, I am simply using the api, thus making a Http request to get the information.

Method to get the information (in a provider):

```js
 getGeoCodefromGoogleAPI(address: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Method call ->

```js
this._deliveryAddressService.getGeoCodefromGoogleAPI(event.description).subscribe(addressData => {

        let latitude: string = addressData.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        let longitude: string = addressData.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        }
```

Of course, there needs to be the due process of registering for the key.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem of the plugin. You need just to add more one so you can ask permission to activate the `High Accuracy` in the phone.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/location-accuracy/